# Local variable "ANSWER" is not used (pycharm)

Tags: variables, pycharm, restart, local-variables

I know similar questions have been asked before and I've been dabbling with this section of code for a few hours now, can anyone help me out please?

This code is within a function called game(), which has a while loop and this is the 'else' part of that while loop.

```
    else:
        ANSWER = input("Sorry, game over. Would you like to try again? \'y/n\'")
        if 'y' or 'yes' == ANSWER:
            game()
        elif 'n' or 'no' == ANSWER:
            print("See you next time.")
            break
        else:
            ANSWER = input("Sorry, I didn't get that. Restart? \'y/n\'")

game()
```

Pycharm is telling me that local variable ANSWER is not used' for the last line of code. Is my indentation off? Is it because I'm reassigning ANSWER? I tried earlier doing ANSWER == if 'y' or 'yes': (and the same format for the "no" line) and neither have made a difference, so that's not the problem..

Also, no matter what I type for answer, it carries out the 'game()' command on the 4th line displayed. I could type "alksdfj"  and it would restart the game.

Thanks

Comment: 1) "Is my indentation off?" - it's impossible to tell without seeing more of your code. 2) "I tried earlier doing ANSWER == if 'y' or 'yes': ...so that's not the problem." Yes it is *one* of the problems. Your test is always true. `if 'y' or 'yes' == ANSWER` is evaluated as True because `if 'y'` is always true. What you want is `if (ANSWER=='y') or (ANSWER=='yes'):`. The same applies to the elif statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without seeing more code around, but it looks like the pattern you have boils down to this:

```
begin loop
   assign value1 to ANSWER
   read from ANSWER
   assign value2 to ANSWER
end loop
```

If you "unroll" that loop, by tracing the lines you reach in turn, you get code that looks like this:

```
assign value1 to ANSWER
read from ANSWER
assign value2 to ANSWER
assign value1 to ANSWER
read from ANSWER
assign value2 to ANSWER
```

So every time you assign value2 to ANSWER, you immediately overwrite it with value1 (next time around the loop).

What you presumably want is more like this:

```
assign value1 to ANSWER
begin loop
   read from ANSWER
   assign value2 to ANSWER
end loop
```

Which unrolls like this:

```
assign value1 to ANSWER
read from ANSWER
assign value2 to ANSWER
read from ANSWER
assign value2 to ANSWER
```

So now, when we go round the loop, we still have value2 to read from.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not using `ANSWER`. When Python looks at your `if` statement it evaluates `'y'` to be `True`, so it never evaluate `'yes' == ANSWER`. Try:

```
if ANSWER.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
```

Same thing for your `elif` statement.